# Access GridView inside another GridView from code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I create in ascx page 3 GridViews, like:

```
<dxwgv:ASPxGridView ID="grid1" ..... >
    <dxwgv:ASPxGridView ID="grid2" .... >
      <dxwgv:ASPXGridView ID="grid3" ....>
      </dxwgv>
    </dxwgv>
 </dxwgv>
```

But in code-behind I see only first grid (grid1) ID and can control only it. How to use others?

Comment: Are the other grids are added as Item templates or what?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with grid2 and grid3? Where should they render?

Comment: provide the actual markup that you are using to display gridview inside gridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
GridView grid2 = (GridView)grid1.FindControl("grid2")
GridView grid3 = (GridView)grid2.FindControl("grid3")
```

should work.

Comment: i think this is not a complete answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You will not see the other gridviews since they are hidden in the first grid view, to access the other gridviews you should do the following:

1. create by code two grid view controls lets say name them: GVsubone
   and GVsubtwo
2. in the RowDataBound of the first gridview (the one visible for you) make your GVsubone handles the events of your grid2 like this `grid2.RowDataBound += new EventHandler(GVsubone.RowDataBound);`
3. and then in the GVsubone RowDataBound you have to do the same logic to handle the events for grid 2

P.S. you can handle any event RowDataBound was an example.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to assign unique IDs (and ClientInstanceNames), as well as scripts, to controls at runtime.
This approach is described in the following Knowledge Base article: [The general technique of using the Init/Load event handler.](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/K18282.aspx)

and then another approach is that handle the [ASPxGridView.DataBound](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxClassesASPxDataWebControlBase_DataBoundtopic) event of the detail grid and get a reference to the grid via the sender parameter. Here  you can call the [ASPxGridView.FindDetailRowTemplateContro](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_FindDetailRowTemplateControltopic)l method of the master grid if you are using **Master Details**.

> If you are using GridView's DataRowTemplate then use the
>   [ASPxGridView.FindRowTemplateControl Method](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_FindRowTemplateControltopic), you just need to get
>   the visibleIndex of the row and you are able to access the grid with
>   it's name.

If you are using Coloumn template then use  [ASPxGridView.FindRowCellTemplateControl Method](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_FindRowCellTemplateControltopic)

```
 protected void ASPxGridView1_HtmlDataCellPrepared(object sender, ASPxGridViewTableDataCellEventArgs e) {
        if(e.DataColumn.FieldName == "title") {
            ASPxTextBox textBox = ASPxGridView1.FindRowCellTemplateControl(e.VisibleIndex, e.DataColumn, "ASPxTextBox1") as ASPxTextBox;
            textBox.Text = Convert.ToString(e.CellValue);
        }
    }
```

Reference these:
[ASPxGridView - How to access controls inside DetailRow on the client side](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q383100.aspx)